# initializing reference variable to a pointer using a function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

why am I unable to initialize reference variable with a predefined pointer variable through function ?

```
int * f(int * p) {
    return p;
}

int main(){
    int  s=10;
    int *p=&s;
    int *&ref1 = p;    //no error given here
    int *&ref2 = f(p); //gives error cannot initialize int * & with int * why??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because you are trying to reference the pointer returned by `f(p)`, which is a temporary that goes out of scope right at the end of the expression. You would create a dangling reference and the compiler is preventing you from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer by value here:

```
int* f(int* p)
^^^^
```

It's a copy, a temporary, meaning you can't hold a reference to it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to propose the "fix" without seeing the implementation of `f`? You might just create the next and much worse problem by creating a dangling reference that the compiler did not catch.

Comment: @DanielFrey I'm assuming he's returning the pointer created inside `main`.

Comment: And how would you get that pointer? Note the parameter to `f` is a *copy* of that pointer, so you can't return a reference to that!

Comment: thanks Daniel and 0x499602D2 and one more thing


can I initialize a reference variable which is declared with function arguments ?
like:
   f(int * &ref);

somewhere in main: f(p); where p is a pointer calling f

Comment: @DanielFrey okay. Got it

Comment: @AbhishekSen Yes, you can do this. But I'd much rather advise smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @AbhishekSen You have a reference, so you can set/modify what is referenced, yes.